# current FRA quotation

Tags: finance

where can I find the current FRA (Forwad Rate Agreement) quotes? I know this is an OTC contract, but I would like to see what the rates for such contracts look like at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The usual places - dealer runs, BBG, Refinitiv.

EDIT: for USD, EUR, GBP, CHF and AUD, you might as well look at STIR futures unless you're after 6m rather than 3m rates.

Comment: I need this information for my presentation about FRA contract but I dont know this sites. Where exactly can I  find these numbers?

Comment: For FRAs, you will - AFAIK - need access to Bloomberg or Refinitiv's Eikon product. For futures, I suggest you look at the exchange websites. CME for Eurodollars, ICE for EURIBOR / Short Sterling / Euroswiss, SFE/ASX for Aussie Bank Bills.